# Using beautiful soup to get all mp3 files from a website -- recursively

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Difficult to find answers for this question here, I know I've been searching for over an hour now. Many come close, I've tried bits and pieces from some of them but still the solution evades me. (Until now, see update)

Trying to pull all MP3 files from https://www.crrow777radio.com/free-episodes/, but they are deeply nested. I thought I could provide that URL and bs would recursively follow all links and I filter them to get my specific files to download. Apparently each href found must then be requested and parsed for the links on that page.

I have code that will pull the MP3 from the page that contains it, but doing that for all such pages (from top down recursively) is not as easy as the bs docs lead me to believe it is.

**Update**: With the help of MendelG and others elsewhere I have revised the code. I believe this will do the job, but getting the [large size] file content into a variable may need improvement via some sort of download write, download write scheme to reduce memory impact:

```
def getMP3sOnPageP(session, h, p):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(p, headers=h).content, "html.parser")

    # Select all the buttons on this page with the text `LISTEN`
    for tag in soup.select("a.button"):
        # Extracts the link from the button, in order to perform a request to that page
        page = tag["href"]
        soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(page, headers=h).content, "html.parser")

        # Finds the link to the mp3 file
        download_link = soup.select_one("a.btn[download]")["href"]
        file_name = re.search(r'(\d+-Hour-1.mp3)', download_link.split("/")[-1]).group()

        # Request the mp3 file
        print("Downloading ", file_name)
        mp3_file = session.get(download_link).content
        with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
            f.write(mp3_file)

HEADERS = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"}
with requests.Session() as session:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(URL, headers=HEADERS).content, "html.parser")

    # Select all the links on this page with a class of "page-numbers"
    for a in soup.select("a.page-numbers"):
        getMP3sOnPageP(session, HEADERS, a.get("href"))
```

As you can see this required 3 calls to beautiful soup (bs). My reading of the docs lead me to believe bs would operate recursively such that a single call with the correct filtering / parameters would be sufficient. If it is I definitely don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

The update I provided solved the question I had. Although user MendelG posted a reply it didn't address the entire problem, although it was very helpful. His contribution is embodied in the getMP3sOnPageP function in my update.